# Искажение фотографии с помощью Python Pillow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow

Как можно исказить фотографию, как показано ниже, по пикселям разброс делать или сужать, или вообще другое?

[image: Исходное изображение]

[image: Конечный результат]

Comment: Похоже на то, что то что вам нужно находится здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071063/is-there-a-library-for-image-warping-image-morphing-for-python-with-controlled/37350619#37350619

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Меня зацепило в вопросе `или вообще другое?`.

А потому что я [могу показать что-то другое](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/9e46c5a37fd4b46eed5accf08d18567b391b4525/pil_pillow__examples/pixelate_image), как вам пикселизация?

```
from PIL import Image


def pixelate(image, pixel_size=9, draw_margin=True):
    margin_color = (0, 0, 0)

    image = image.resize((image.size[0] // pixel_size, image.size[1] // pixel_size), Image.NEAREST)
    image = image.resize((image.size[0] * pixel_size, image.size[1] * pixel_size), Image.NEAREST)
    pixel = image.load()

    # Draw black margin between pixels
    if draw_margin:
        for i in range(0, image.size[0], pixel_size):
            for j in range(0, image.size[1], pixel_size):
                for r in range(pixel_size):
                    pixel[i+r, j] = margin_color
                    pixel[i, j+r] = margin_color

    return image


if __name__ == '__main__':
    image = Image.open('image/input.jpg').convert('RGB')
    # image.show()

    image_pixelate = pixelate(image, draw_margin=False)
    image_pixelate.save('image/output_no_margin.jpg')
    # image_pixelate.show()

    image_pixelate = pixelate(image)
    image_pixelate.save('image/output.jpg')
    # image_pixelate.show()

    for size in (16, 32, 48):
        image_pixelate = pixelate(image, pixel_size=size)
        image_pixelate.save('image/output_{}.jpg'.format(size))
        # image_pixelate.show()
```

---

Результаты:

**pixel_size=9**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**pixel_size=16**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**pixel_size=32**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**pixel_size=48**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**pixel_size=9, draw_margin=False**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Под другое я имел введу способ, но спасибо большое за вариант